# How to Call A Function inside a Ko.Observable Array? Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm learning more about knockout.js. I have built a little dialogue system using it and it works! One thing I'd like to do, is have a function that can jump from the data after a button is pressed to run a new function.

---

How the data below works is there's text that shows, the image changes, and the choices are buttons that when pressed go to the next story/data set. In this case it goes back to the start (storyLink 1).

Here's a snippet of my data with said function:

```
 "106":{"text":"[The game ended you Died.]",
  "image": "death face.gif",
  "choices":[{"choiceText":"Oops.","storyLink":"1", function () { console.log("lmao");}}]},
```

here is a snippet of the html:

```
    <div data-bind="with: activeStory">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: image }">
<button id ="button" class ="Button-data imgLink" onclick = "handleClick()" data-bind="click: $root.onChoice, text: choiceText"></button>
```

here's a bit of the view model. I did not include the part where the bindings are applied as that's a chunk of code that takes the text above and creates a typewriter effect.

```
var activeStoryId = ko.observable(1)

  .extend({ notify: "always" });
  
  var activeStory = ko.pureComputed(() => 
  story[activeStoryId()] ?? 

  { text: "[There was an Error.]", choices: [{ choiceText: "Back to start", storyLink: 1 }] }
);

var onChoice = ({ storyLink }) => activeStoryId(storyLink);

    // Apply bindings
      registerBinding();
      ko.applyBindings({
        onChoice,
        activeStory
      });
```

This isn't running, and I assume this is because of a syntax error or perhaps I need to call it a different way. I keep finding my syntax is wrong when using knockout so any insight would be great!

I tried adjusting the syntax based on Javascript arrays and I'm still missing something. I haven't found a solution that works yet.

Edit 2:
Here's an example of what I am trying to figure out:

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

let arr = [
  a,
  b,
  function () {
    return a + b;
   },
  ];

console.log(arr[2]()); // return 3
console.log(typeof arr); // returns object
```

In this code, there's a function that runs inside the array. It doesn't currently work in my code when I try to do this.

Comment: Is this part of a homework assignment?  To work out what you are doing can you create a small working example or include enough code of the HTML and ViewModel of the knockout code to help understand.

Comment: @Martlark

It's a personal Project. I didn't want to put down the entire view model because it's pretty big. It runs a typewriter code so it displays the text in the data one character at a time.  The edit is up, but my focus is on syntax for calling functions within the data. I know I can do this in js arrays, but wasn't sure if it could be applied here.

Comment: Note that `{ function() { } }` is very different from `[ function() { } ]`. The first creates an object with a property named `function`, the second creates an array with an anonymous function inside at `[0]`.

Your `a,b` example uses `[]`, but the snippet of your data shows `choices: [ { choiceText, ..., function() { } } ]`

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are tying to do.  Hopefully this will help.

```js
var story = {
  "1": {
    "text": "[The game ended you Died.]",
    "image": "death_face.gif",
    "choices": [{
      "choiceText": "Oops.",
      "storyLink": "1"
    }, {
      "choiceText": "So close...",
      "storyLink": "2"
    }]
  },
  "2": {
    "text": "[Start New Story]",
    "image": "happy_face.gif",
    "choices": [{
      "choiceText": "Away we go.",
      "storyLink": "1"
    }, {
      "choiceText": "Maybe next time",
      "storyLink": "2"
    }]
  }
};

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.activeStoryId = ko.observable(1)
    .extend({
      notify: "always"
    });

  self.activeStory = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    story[self.activeStoryId()] ?? {
      text: "[There was an Error.]",
      choices: [{
        choiceText: "Back to start",
        storyLink: 1
      }]
    }
  );

  self.onChoice = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    self.activeStoryId(item.storyLink);
  }
}

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: activeStory">
  <h2 data-bind="text: text"></h2>
  <img data-bind="attr: { src: image }">
  <!-- ko foreach: choices -->
  <button id="button" class="Button-data imgLink" data-bind="click: $root.onChoice, text: choiceText"></button>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**EDIT**
If I understand correctly, if you want to be passing functions as part of your data, I would do something like the following.  Have a function name that is the same across your choice objects. then you can pass that function object to the click binding for it to run.

```js
var story = {
  "1": {
    "text": "[The game ended you Died.]",
    "image": "death_face.gif",
    "choices": [{
      "choiceText": "Oops.",
      "storyLink": "1",
      "choiceCommand": function () { console.log("storylink 1-1")}
    }, {
      "choiceText": "So close...",
      "storyLink": "2",
      "choiceCommand": function () { console.log("storylink 1-2")}
    }]
  },
  "2": {
    "text": "[Start New Story]",
    "image": "happy_face.gif",
    "choices": [{
      "choiceText": "Away we go.",
      "storyLink": "1",
      "choiceCommand": function () { console.log("storylink 2-1")}
    }, {
      "choiceText": "Maybe next time",
      "storyLink": "2",
      "choiceCommand": function () { console.log("storylink 2-2")}
    }]
  }
};

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.activeStoryId = ko.observable(1)
    .extend({
      notify: "always"
    });

  self.activeStory = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    story[self.activeStoryId()] ?? {
      text: "[There was an Error.]",
      choices: [{
        choiceText: "Back to start",
        storyLink: 1
      }]
    }
  );

  self.onChoice = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    self.activeStoryId(item.storyLink);
  }
}

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: activeStory">
  <h2 data-bind="text: text"></h2>
  <img data-bind="attr: { src: image }">
  <!-- ko foreach: choices -->
  <button id="button" class="Button-data imgLink" data-bind="click: choiceCommand, text: choiceText"></button>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like it's calling storylink, which is currently how my code runs. Are we able to  call functions within the data/array? I know I can do this in js arrays, but wasn't sure if it could be applied here. The code I have works, but the snippet with the function inside the data doesn't work (first example). I assume It's possible but I'm just missing the syntax. Do I have to create an observable like storylink to do this? (My terminology is limited, sorry if I am causing confusion!)